# what are the extrema and saddle points of $f(x,y)= (x − 1)(4 − x^2 − y^2 )$?

Tags: calculus

1. This question is about finding the extreme value and saddle point of the second partial derivative of calculus.
   we have $f(x,y)=(x-1)(4-x^2-y^2)$, how to find the extrema and saddle point of this  two or more variables by differentiating wrt one variable?
2. $x $ and $y$ need to conduct a derivative, and the first derivative is 0, the function obtains saddle point. Perform the second derivative of the function on $x$, $y$ and $xy$, and judge the extreme value through the positive and negative values of the Hessian matrix and the second derivative of $x$.
3. For this question, I calculated that there are 7 saddle points in total, and calculated that there are two maximums. I want to know how to solve this problem.
   I calculate according to the problem-solving steps I said, but I don't know whether it is correct or there is a better problem-solving step.